# Dynamic columns select depending on its values

Tags: sql, select, dynamic

I have a table that has a lot of columns and I need to select only some of them depending on there value. How can I write such a SELECT.

for instance: SELECT columns only that have sum of its all rows values < 10 and the ones that are >= 10 are selected...

Comment: Can you provide table schema and some data, and what you tried..!!!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT SUM(column1), SUM(column2), SUM(column3)
INTO #temptable
FROM TableName
GROUP BY column1, column2, column3

SELECT column1
FROM #temptable
WHERE column1 < 10
```

or

```
SELECT column1
FROM #temptable
WHERE column1 >= 10
```

Is this what you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: I think you did not quite got me

Comment: i need to select variable number of columns from a table based on some condition!!! So that every time I execute this select I get different number of Columns!!!

Comment: You need to include wayyyy more information in your question then

Answer (score 0):

From your original description (wanting to select data based on the results of an aggregate function), you'll most likely want to use the HAVING clause. Take a look at http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_having.asp for more information.

Answer (score 0):

maybe something like this?

```
Select Name
FROM TableName.Columns
WHERE
  SELECT SUM(*) AS subtotal
  FROM Name
  WHERE subtotal >=10
```

Answer (score 0):

if you wanna create dynamic sql f.e. inside a procedure you can use [sp_executesql](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms188001.aspx)

therefore you have to build your select as a string/varchar and call sp_executesql with your selectstring and in/out parameters.

this is for ms sql server. there are procedures for oracle and other databases as well.

```
DECLARE @SQLString nvarchar(500); /* dynamic sql string */
DECLARE @customer_id int; /* input variable */
DECLARE @name varchar(30); /* output variable */
DECLARE @ParmDefinition nvarchar(500); /* connection for binding variables */


SET @customer_id= 197; 

/* Add your condition here to build different select strings */
SET @SQLString = N'SELECT @name_out = name
   FROM customers
   WHERE cusomersid = @custid_in';

SET @ParmDefinition = N'@custid_in tinyint, @name_out varchar(30) OUTPUT';

EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQLString, @ParmDefinition, @custid_in = @customer_id, @name_out = @name  OUTPUT;
SELECT @name;
```

https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/revision/126004/154483/dynamic-sql